# Does the limit of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ at $u=0$ exist?

Tags: optimization, numerical-analysis, jacobian, calculus

For an optimization routine I needed to compute the derivative of the right-hand side $\: f_u(x_k, u_k)$ of a discrete-time system $x_{k+1} = f(x_k, u_k)$. Since $\: f_u(x_k, u_k)$ includes terms that are divided by $u_k$, it is not possible to evaluate $f(x_k, u_k=0)$. From the physics, it's pretty clear that a limit must exist. The numerics poses a problem here, though. Any idea, how I could circumvent it?

---

To illustrate the behavior, I added a double logarithmic plot showing $f_u(x_k, u_k)$ as $u \rightarrow 0$. It doesn't make any sense that $f_u$ escapes here. What the plot does not show is that there are multiple sign changes of $f_u$ as $u$ drops below $10^{-4}$, let's say.

[image: loglog plot of $f_u(x_k, u_k)$ as $u_k \rightarrow 0$]

---

The function $f_u(x_k, u_k)$ is defined as follows:

$$
f_u(x, u) = \partial_u \int_0^T \int_0^t \sin(x_5 + x_6 \tau + u \frac{\tau^2}{2}) \: d\tau.
$$

I had a CAS do the job of analytically integrating and derivating the sine term. As already pointed out this produces some division by $u$ which causes the problems when it comes to evaluating at $u=0$.

Comment: Do you have the analytical form of $f$? If so, can you post it here?

Comment: It's 2845 characters long. I better don't.

Comment: I would segregate out the part that involves division by $u$ (which might be smaller than the 2800+ characters long).  To that part I would try to apply l'Hopital's Rule to get the limit as $u\to 0$.

Comment: I don't think I understand -- is $f(x,u=0)$ finite, or does it go to infinity? In the former case, you can apply l'Hopital's rule, as suggested. In the latter case, however, the function is not continuous at $u=0$, and consequently also not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for your remark @WolfgangBangerth. The problem with $f_u(x,u)$ is that I can tell it's finite everywhere where $u$ resides just from the system's properties. But the term is huge and contains some divisions by $u$, which makes a numerical approach pointless. I was hoping that there was another way to handle that problem, but going manually through the terms and see how they behave as $u \rightarrow 0$ by mathematical reasoning.

Comment: OK, in that case l'Hopital's rule is useful. Of course you can also evaluate the derivative by approximating the expression $f_u(x,u=0)= \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x,2\varepsilon)-f(x,\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$ which avoids the evaluation at $u=0$.

Comment: Have you tried using a [CAS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) for your limit? You can use SymPy online [here](http://live.sympy.org), for example.

Comment: I tried Mathematica and it failed.

Comment: Can you evaluate $f(x,u)$ for small $u$, or is the error just as bad as for $f_u$? Is the function holomorphic? I feel the question would be much clearer if you said more about the function. Even at 3k characters, can you at least put it into something like a gist (https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Kirill. I totally agree with you and Bill Barth. It's tedious talking about some bad behaving algorithm with knowing as little as some character count. I'll provide as much information on it as possible in the next few hours.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann I got the full series for the integrand of $f_u$ in $u$ as $$\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}{2^n (n-1)!}\tau^{2n}Q_n u^{n-1}, $$ where $Q_n$ is $\cos(x_5+x_6\tau)$ (odd $n$), or $\sin(x_5+x_6\tau)$ (even $n$). I expect it's more accurate to take more terms than just the first one. [Incidentally, if you've answered your own question with this, please submit a full answer — [SE encourages people to answer their own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).]

Answer (score 6):

Given that $u \frac{\tau^2}{2} \ll 1$, one way of tackling the numerical oscillations, even *before* the actual term emerges, is a Taylor approximation in $u$ of the sine term (Thanks to Kirill for the full series):

$$ \sin(\underbrace{x_5 + x_6 \tau}_{u_0} + \underbrace{u \frac{\tau^2}{2}}_{\Delta u}) = \sin(x_5 + x_6 \tau) + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}{2^n(n-1)!} \tau^{2n}Q_nu^{n} + o(\Delta u^{N}),$$

where

$$ Q_n = 
\begin{cases}
\cos(x_5 + x_6 \tau) & n \text{ odd} \\
\sin(x_5 + x_6 \tau) & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Introducing this approximation into the original equation and exchanging order of integration and differentiation gives

$$ 
\begin{array}{ll}
f_u(x,u) & = \int_0^T \int_0^t \partial_u \left( \sin(x_5 + x_6 \tau) + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}{2^n(n-1)!} \tau^{2n}Q_nu^{n} + o(\Delta u^{N}) \right) \: d\tau \\
& = \int_0^T \int_0^t \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}}{2^n(n-1)!} \tau^{2n}Q_nu^{n-1} + o(\Delta u^{N-1}) \: d\tau.
\end{array} $$

A first-order approximation ($N=1$) is then given as

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
f_u(x,u) & \approx \int_0^T \int_0^t \cos(x_5 + x_6 \tau) \frac{\tau^2}{2} \: d\tau \\
& = \frac{-3 \cos(x_5)}{x_6^4} + \frac{(6-T^2x_6^2)\cos(x_5 + Tx_6) + 2Tx_6(\sin(x_5) + 2 \sin(x_5 + Tx_6))}{2x_6^4},
\end{array}
$$

which does not depend on $u$, naturally.